# Can explain how the output is coming like this?

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

```
public class A {
  public A(){
    System.out.println("A created");        
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new B();
  }
}

class B extends A{
    public B(){
        System.out.println("B created");
    }       
}
```

the output of the above program will be

```
A created

B created
```

I can't understand how the constructor A() is invoked.There is no super called in B(). But still  A() is invoked.

Answer (score 7):

When class `B` extends class `A`, it will call constructor `A( )` by default.

That's the reason why the program prints `A created` before `B created`.

Answer (score 2):

In child classes, `super()` is automatically called implicitly to ensure the object is properly constructed.